# How to iterate or loop through folders that match a certain condition

Tags: windows, powershell

I have directory that contains folders that correspond to dates (i.e. dated subfolders). They are all in the same format of `yyyymmdd`. There are other folders within this directory as well, that have names that are text. What I'm trying to do is write a script that will take a user inputting how many days previous they would like to see. The script will then perform some action on each folder. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get a list of all of the folders correctly.

The directory will look something like:

```
C:--/
    FOO--/
         --20190525
         --20190526
         --20190527
         --20190528
         --20190529
         --20190530
         --20190531
         --20190601
         --20190602
etc.
```

I currently am using a for loop, but the issue is that when the end of the month occurs, i.e. 20190531, the loop will continue to 20190532 instead of 20190601.

```bsh
$lastday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$lastdayint = [int]$lastday
$days = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('How many days back do you want to process?')
if ($days.Length -eq 0) {
    Exit
}
$daysint = [int]$days
$firstday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysint).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$firstdayint = [int]$firstday

for ($i = $firstdayint; $i -le $lastdayint; $i++) {
    # Get our dated sub folder by looking through the root of FOO
    # and finding the folder that matches the condition
    $datedsub = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\FOO\*" | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -eq [string]$i) } ).Name
    # If the path does not exist, both processes will fail, so exit out of the loop and move on to the next date
    if ( $( try { !(Test-Path -Path ("C:\FOO\$datedsub").Trim() -PathType Container) } catch { $false } ) ) {
        Continue
    }
}
```

I'm kind of stuck figuring out how to get all of the folders with names between 2 dates. This was pretty easy to do in CMD scripting, as everything is a string and folders don't have properties. But with Powershell, it's a bit more difficult. 
What the script needs to do is loop through all of the folders in a specified range. I'm pretty sure a foreach loop would probably be my best bet, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified in algorithm:

```
[int]$days = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('How many days back do you want to process?')
if ($days.Length -eq 0) {
    Exit
}

# will contain folders
$dirlist = @()

# note: includes today. To not include today, start $i at 1
for ($i = 0; $i -le $days; $i++) {
    $datestr = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$i).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    $dir = Get-ChildItem -Path $datestr -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($null -ne $dir) {
        [void]$dirlist.Add($dir)
        # Or do work here. Otherwise you can use the outputted arraylist
    }
}

# prints folders to console
$dirlist
```

The above:

1. Asks user for number of days back
2. Saves that number of days and loops that many times
3. Gets the date string using Today - `$i`
4. Uses `Get-ChildItem` with `-Path` to find the item, `-Directory` to limit to directories, and `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress errors (if it does not exist it will return `$null`)
5. Adds to `ArrayList` if not `$null`

Comment: This was mostly what I did. The array was definitely what I was looking for. Biggest change was `$dirlist += $dir` as declaring the array ahead of time set it's size. I also reversed the array so it started with the oldest date and then did `foreach ($dateddir in $dirlist) { ....etc. }` to loop through the array and do work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the string to an integer and incrementing that, you should use `AddDays()` to loop through the actual dates:

```
$days = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('How many days back do you want to process?')
if ($days.Length -eq 0) {
    Exit
}
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)
$endDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

for($currentDate = $startDate; $currentDate -le $endDate; $currentDate.AddDays(1)) {
    $dateString = $currentDate.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    if ( -not( Test-Path "C:\FOO\$dateString" -PathType Container ) ) {
        continue
    }
    # do work here
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. It seemed like the `$currentdate.AddDays(1)` wasn't actually incrementing the day.